# Converting date not working on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to convert a date to a specific dormat but it seems to be not working.

I launch this request:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2014-05-02', 101)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2014-05-02', 101)
```

It returns the following result:

2014-05-02 00:00:00.000

2014-05-02

From this documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx the code 101 should return a date with following format mm/dd/yy.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should have your solution provided below but I just wanted to caution you about using any date format with your SQL 2000 that is not in the *yyyymmdd* format mask as you can receive unpredictable results if fed back into a `SELECT` as criteria or some-such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It will convert. But only on the `DATETIME` value, not the `CHAR` value. `CAST` your input in `CHAR` to `DATETIME` then do the `CONVERT`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST('2014-05-02' AS DATETIME), 101)
```